# Resource is override in Android

Tags: android

I have library project and main project. In library project, I have an icon with `R.id.ic_generic_error` and in main project, I have the alternative icon with the same id. In runtime, my app always display main project version of icon although I use package name like that `com.libraryname.R.id.ic_generic_error`.

Now I wanna use the icon of library. is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a different resource name to the library icon. Library resources are always overridden by project resources with the same name.

If you need the `ic_generic_error` icon to exist in the library project (because, for instance, it is referenced in a layout or in code), you can create an alias to the renamed library icon. See [Creating alias resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources) for info on how to do this.